# Understanding “Putin’s fiercest critics worry he's pushing to take over territory”

Tags: word-meaning

> Putin's **fiercest¹** critics worry he's **pushing²** to **take over³ territory⁴**
> <sub>Source: [CNN World – *What is Putin's endgame in Ukraine?* – Story Highlights](http://www.cnn.com/2014/08/07/world/europe/russia-putin-ukraine-endgame/index.html)</sub>

1. Does the word **“fiercest”** mean **most serious**?
2. What does the word **“pushing”** mean?
3. What place is the word **“territory”** referring to? Ukraine?
4. What does **“take over”** mean?

Comment: Saying where this headline came from isn't required, but it would be [a gesture appreciated by many](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1084).

Answer (score 7):

1. 'fiercest critics' means those who are the most critical (they disagree with his actions the most, or at least the loudest).
2. 'push' means 'trying'.
3. The headline does not specify. 'Territory' just means land - any land. Presumably the article would provide more detail.
4. 'take over' means gain control of.